# What is the method of polynomial division?

Tags: polynomials

What is Horner's method? I can't understand Wikipedia's language. Is this only to be used for monomial divisors? How is synthetic division different from it?

Can anyone please elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

Horner's method is not essentially different than synthetic division. It's simply an algorithmic method to compute, for a polynomial $p(x)$ and a point $a$, the value $p(a)$ and, simultaneously, to obtain the coefficients of the polynomial $q(x)$ such that $p(x)=q(x)(x-a)+p(a)$. It was shown that Horner's method is optimal both in terms of number of additions and of number of multiplications requires to perform the evaluation/division.

Comment: How we have reached from older algorithmic form to modern division